# How can I tell if my game saves are backed up?

Tags: ps4, playstation-plus

I'm a PlayStation Plus subscriber. On my PS3, I get a message every day saying which game saves were backed up that night. On the PS4, I don't get any messages about the success or failure of my game saves. **Is there a place I can verify my game saves are being backed up? Is there a way I can get notified whenever a game save is backed up?** I'd hate to discover too late that the hours and hours I've spent on some of my games are for nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check which games have been backed up, manage your backed up files and restore save files from online storage by selecting **(Settings) > [Application Saved Data Management] > [Saved Data in Online Storage]** from the cross media bar.

If you are a PS+ subscriber and you have an internet connection your PS4 should automatically back you all your save files to online storage. It will only inform you if there is a problem with the process, such as no more storage space or a failed upload.

I don't think there is currently an option to turn on notifications for successful back ups but I am currently away from my PS4 so I can't check. You can see what notifications are you will receive from the following menu **(Settings) > [Notifications]**.

[Source - PlayStation 4 Online user Guide](http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps4/settings/data_online.html)

Answer (score 0):

On the PS4, you will only receive a notification if something went wrong. Otherwise, when everything runs fine, you will not be notified.

Answer (score -4):

If you have saved your games on the PS4, and they don't send a message saying that they're backed up and saved, you would still have them saved. As long as you saved it and backed it up. PS4 does not do that right now and still has some bugs.

Comment: 'As long as you saved it and backed it up. PS4 does not do that right now and still has some bugs.' -- This doesn't make sense.