# Is there a way to more frequently upload save data to the cloud?

Tags: ps4

Last night while playing Absolver, my game crashed a few times. The last time it crashed, however, I was horrified to find out that my save data had become corrupted and, based on the [the devs' own post on the official website](https://absolvergame.com/news/update-on-online-stability-region-lock-and-ps4-related-save-issues), it was clear that my save data is unsalvageable.

However, I found [this wonderful PSA](https://www.reddit.com/r/absolver/comments/6wrb47/psa_for_ps4_users/) that explained the ability to download save data from the cloud to prevent losses when Absolver save data gets corrupted. Excitedly, I downloaded my save data from the cloud. Unexcitedly, I realized this data was from a full day before, meaning I'd only just completed the tutorial, meaning I still pretty much had to start over (the downloaded save data has 18 minutes of playtime).

To avoid this kind of pain and suffering in the future, is there a way to set an interval at which the PS4 uploads save data to the cloud? In this case, the data uploaded was from after I'd quit for the night the previous night, so it was after I'd put the PS4 in rest mode.

I understand [how to find out what save data is currently in the cloud and when it was uploaded](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/246399/162442), but is there some sort of setting that allows me to tell the PS4 to upload save data every x hours, even while actively using the console? Manually doing this would be a bit of a chore (it's not like I *know* when a game will crash and corrupt my save data), so I'm hoping for an automatic setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this link from Sony](http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps4/settings/data_upload.html), when you log out of PSN (manually logging out, or in functions like going to rest mode/shutting down) the PS4 checks for newly saved data, and attempts an upload. However, the page does not go into great detail on the timing of these uploads.

[This GameFAQs link](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/691087-playstation-4/68162654) seems to be largely speculation. A user does mention that you can manually upload data files by doing the following:

> Settings -> Application Saved Data Management -> Saved Data in System Storage -> Upload to Online Storage -> [Game or App] -> [File you want to upload] -> Upload.

It's an unfortunate annoyance that the manual process is so difficult, especially since you don't know when the game is going to crash. As of right now, there doesn't seem to be a way to increase the upload frequency.